# How to leave only the following strings?

Tags: list-manipulation, data

Consider a data having the form

```
data = {{1,7,4,6},{1,6,4,8},{2,4,9,2},{E,...},{1,4,6,3},{4,4,6,2},{E,...},...}
```

i.e., some number $n_{1}$ of rows followed by row $\{E,...\}$, then some number $n_{2}$ of rows followed by row $\{E,...\}$ and so on.

Could you please tell me how to leave only the last rows before $\{E,\}$, i.e. to obtain

```
subdata= {{2,4,9,2},{4,4,6,2},...}?
```

Comment: e.g. `SequenceCases[data, {x_List, {E, ___}} :> x]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most idiomatic solution to this problem is, in my opinion, pattern matching (as Sakra has also answered):

```
SequenceCases[data, {x_List, {E, ___}} :> x]
```

> `{{2, 4, 9, 2}, {4, 4, 6, 2}}`

But the problem also lends itself to functional solutions, e.g.:

```
pairs = Partition[data, 2, 1];
If[#[[2, 1]] == E, #[[1]], Nothing] & /@ pairs
```

> `{{2, 4, 9, 2}, {4, 4, 6, 2}}`

Or in one go:

```
BlockMap[If[#[[2, 1]] == E, #[[1]], Nothing] &, data, 2, 1]
```

> `{{2, 4, 9, 2}, {4, 4, 6, 2}}`

Answer (score 6):

Try [SequenceCases](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html):

```
data = {{1, 7, 4, 6}, {1, 6, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 9, 2}, {E, 1, 2, 3}, 
        {1, 4, 6, 3}, {4, 4, 6, 2}, {E, 4, 5, 6}}
SequenceCases[data, {p_, {E, ___}} :> p]
```

yields

```
{{2, 4, 9, 2}, {4, 4, 6, 2}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data =
  {{1, 7, 4, 6}, {1, 6, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 9, 2}, {e, "..."},
   {1, 4, 6, 3}, {4, 4, 6, 2}, {e, "..."}};

Extract[data, Position[data, {e, _}] - 1]
```

{{2, 4, 9, 2}, {4, 4, 6, 2}}

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {{1, 7, 4, 6}, {1, 6, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 9, 2}, {E, 1, 2, 3},
        {1, 4, 6, 3}, {4, 4, 6, 2}, {E, 4, 5, 6}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit`:

```
First /@ SequenceSplit[data, {p_, {Except[E], __}}]

(*{{2, 4, 9, 2}, {4, 4, 6, 2}}*)
```

Or using `Pick` and `Partition`:

```
First /@ Pick[#, ! FreeQ[#[[2]], E] & /@ #] &@Partition[data, 2, 1]

(*{{2, 4, 9, 2}, {4, 4, 6, 2}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using `Split`:**

```
data = {{1, 7, 4, 6}, {1, 6, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 9, 2}, {e, "..."}, {1, 4, 
    6, 3}, {4, 4, 6, 2}, {e, "..."}};

Split[data, First@#1 =!= e &] // Select[Length@# > 1 &] // 
 Map[Last@*Most]
```

---

> {{2, 4, 9, 2}, {4, 4, 6, 2}}